# How can I get the most out of macros in Notepad++?

Tags: macros, automation, dreamweaver, notepad++

What I really want is something similar to Photoshop's automation feature, where you can set it up so it will open a file, preform a macro, and then save the file.

I would prefer if this could be done in Notepad++, but does Dreamweaver or any other IDE have something similar?

I have a couple hundred HTML files that I want to make fairly repetitive modifications to, and really think there is an easier way than doing it manually.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to installing the [Cygwin tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) then the `sed` or `awk` tools might be appropriate for exactly this kind of repetitive editing. I've used `sed` to prepend a license to files that didn't already have an explicit license, rename variables, etc. There isn't much hand-holding with these tools though -- you write little tiny `sed` or `awk` programs to do the job:

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' *  # replace 'foo' with 'bar' in all files in current dir
```